# Read scala stream until criteria has come and gone

Tags: java, scala, stream

I'm reading a stream where I'm looking for json values in a certain time interval. Anything read, before and during values in the time interval, I want to cache. Once the stream has read all values in the time interval (assume chronological order), I should stop reading.

This code here caches all values in a mutable list and then filters to just json in the date range. But it doesn't stop reading once filter completes, it caches everything in the stream.

```
val cache: MutableList[JsValue] = MutableList.empty

pg.pins.flatten
  .map( record => {cache += record; record})
  .filter( js => ( js \ "created_at").as[Date].after(start) && ( js \ "created_at").as[Date].before(end) )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need mutable list for that (avoid using mutable structures unless there is a real reason why you have to). Assuming the `pg.pins` is a `Stream` and that the data is sorted by date (that your question seems to be implying), something like this should do what you want:

```
 val (after, before) = pg.pins.flatten
   .takeWhile { js => (js \ "createdAt").as[Date].before(end) }
   .partition { js => (js \ "createdAt").as[Date].after(start) }
```

Comment: This is great, it's exactly the kind of simplification I was looking for. I know I shouldn't use a mutable if possible, but I'm not sure how else to do it. What you've shown covers data with the date range, but I still need to cache all data before I reach the filter point (separately) as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, I did not realize you wanted to keep it. See updated answer.